# Is there any way to get how much time the pod was in RUNNING state and PENDING state in kubernetes?

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I wanted to calculate Quality of Service of a service. And to get that, I have to calculate how much time pod was in running state and the total time elapsed since pod was created. Is there any way to get these two values in Go?

Comment: The language us called simpy "Go."  "Golang language" is completely redundant.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Get function to get specific POD information (below examples are getting whole Status struct):

> pod, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("kubernetes").Get(pod.Name, metav1.GetOptions{}) fmt.Println(pod.Status)

Also, you can use List function to get all pods in the particular namespace and then range them:

> pods, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("kubernetes").List(metav1.ListOptions{FieldSelector: "metadata.name=kubernetes"}) for _, pod := range pods.Items { fmt.Println(pod.Name, pod.Status) }

Comment: Thanks! Also, where can I look up such commands related to kubernetes?

Comment: Hi @Dragnoid99, already you are working on Go. Change the code in snippet. You can then process the pod events as needed.